# Apple Certificate Expired And Working

Tags: ios, ipad, provisioning-profile

I have an iPad application that has been distributed using an Apple Enterprise account.  The certificate has expired but the application still works on the iPad.  I thought that once the certificate expires then users will not be able to open the application.  Does anyone know when the application will become unusable?  Thanks.

Comment: iPad date is less than today's date, so application is running

Comment: @Prateek what do you mean? I would imagine everything is UTC. Regardless, I've revoked certificates (non-enterprise) and it still worked, although I'm not sure about the official time length.

Comment: @mkral Yes, it uses UTC timing only, but date set on iPad (i.e. iPad system date) is set less than date of provisioning date expiry

Comment: @Prateek eh, I'm sure it's not using user set system dates though. Either way Bejmax seems to have found the official response from Apple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sounds like "3 to 7 days," cache has to expire AND the device needs to be restarted.

From Apple:

> Certificate Validation
>
> The first time an application is opened on a device, the distribution
>   certificate is validated by contactingApple’s OCSP server. Unless the
>   certificate has been revoked, the app is allowed to run. Inability to
>   contactor get a response from the OCSP server is not interpreted as a
>   revocation. To verify the status, the devicemust be able to reach
>   ocsp.apple.com. See“Network Configuration Requirements”(page 9).
>
> The OCSP response is cached on the device for the period of time
>   specified by the OCSP server—currently between 3 and 7 days. The
>   validity of the certificate will not be checked again until the device
>   has restarted and the cached response has expired. If a revocation is
>   received at that time, the app will be prevented from running.
>   Revoking a distribution certificate will invalidate all of the
>   applications you have distributed.
>
> An app will not run if the distribution certificate has expired.
>   Currently, distribution certificates are valid fo rone year. A few
>   weeks before your certificate expires, request a new distribution
>   certificate from the iOS DevCenter, use it to create new distribution
>   provisioning profiles, and then recompile and distribute the updated
>   apps to your users. See “Providing Updated Apps” (page 10)